# How to modify a list if a matrix contain a value?

Tags: python

I have a list with values `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]` and I have a matrix too filled with with 1 and 0.

I want to have a new list that have to be like this:
if there's a 1 into the matrix then sum a '2' into the v's value if it's the first row and sum a '3' it's the second row.

example:

list:

```
v = [5,5,5,5,5]
```

matrix:

```
m = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

final result:

```
v1 = [5,7,10,8,5]
```

Comment: Can you provide the "matrix" as a python object? is it text? numpy array? list?

Comment: @mozway is a list

Answer (score -1):

Create a function that adds array lines, you can have the parameters be 1D numeric arrays. Loops through the arrays and returns a result array that is the addition of each element.

If your task requires it, add a check if the lines are of equal length and abort the function with an error if so.

Run this function on all of the matrix lines and then run it for the result of that and the input array.

Hope I managed to be comprehensive enough

Answer (score -1):

You can use NumPy package for efficient code.

```py
import numpy as np

v = [5,5,5,5,5]
matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

weights = np.array([2,3])
w_matrix = np.multiply(matrix, weights[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=0)

v1 = v + w_matrix
```

Answer (score -1):

##### classical python:

You can use a loop comprehension:

```
to_add = [sum((A*B) for A,B in zip(factors,x)) for x in zip(*m)]
[a+b for a,b in zip(v, to_add)]
```

output: `[5, 7, 10, 8, 5]`

##### numpy:

That said, this is a perfect use case for numpy that is more efficient and less verbose:

```
import numpy as np

v = [5,5,5,5,5]
m = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
factors = [2,3]

V = np.array(v)
M = np.array(m)
F = np.array(factors)

V+(M*F[:,None]).sum(0)
```

output: `array([ 5,  7, 10,  8,  5])`